# Output images to html using python

Tags: python, html, http-headers, cgi

I have a webpage generated from python that works as it should, using:

```
print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
print  ""                                 # blank line, end of headers
print '<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
print "<html><head>"
```

I want to add images to this webpage, but when I do this:

```
sys.stdout.write( "Content-type: image/png\n\n" + file("11.png","rb").read() )
print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
print  ""                                 # blank line, end of headers
print '<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
...
```

All I get is the image, then if I place the image code below my html/text header all I get is the text from the image, ie:

```
<Ï#·öÐÎ´ÝZºm]¾|‰k×®]žòåËÛ¶ÃgžyFK–,ÑôéÓU½zuIÒ}÷Ý§&MšH’V¯^­?üð¼1±±±zýõ×%IñññÚºu«*W®¬wß}W.—K3gÎÔÌ™ÿw‹Ú””I’¹w¤¥hdÒd½q÷X•Šˆ²m¿þfïÞ½*]º´éÈs;¥¤¤Ø¿ILLÔˆ#rÊ
```

Also, if I try:

```
print "<img src='11.png'>"
```

I get a broken image in the browser, and browing directly to the image produces a 500 internal server error, with my apache log saying:

```
8)Exec format error: exec of './../../11.png' failed Premature end of script headers: 11.png
```

Comment: Instead of showing us your print statements, show us the generated html file.

Comment: What is the file/directory layout? It looks like Apache is trying to execute your 11.png as a CGI script. You normally store CGI scripts under `/cgi-bin`, and other resources elsewhere. Are you by any chance mixing them?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use this code to directly embed the image in your HTML:
Python 3

```
import base64
data_uri = base64.b64encode(open('Graph.png', 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(data_uri)
print(img_tag)
```

Python 2.7

```
data_uri = open('11.png', 'rb').read().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(data_uri)

print(img_tag)
```

Alternatively for Python <2.6:

```
data_uri = open('11.png', 'rb').read().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s">' % data_uri

print(img_tag)
```

Comment: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
      args = ("'str' object has no attribute 'format'",)
      message = "'str' object has no attribute 'format'"

Comment: What python version are you on? Seems to be something below 2.6 as str.format was introduced there (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
I added another way to format that should work on 2.5

Comment: I am using 2.6.4, your second suggestion worked, it's the only solution that has so far, thanks, i'll give you the 'tick'! Any idea why i can't simply use "print '<img src=...>'" ?

Comment: you really should use a normal <img src=...>. Work out why it is failing.

Comment: Don't forget to add `import base64` to the script for the Python version > 3 case.

Answer (score 2):

Images in web pages are typically a second request to the server.  The HTML page itself has no images in it, simply references to images like `<img src='the_url_to_the_image'>`.  Then the browser makes a second request to the server, and gets the image data.

The only option you have to serve images and HTML together is to use a `data:` url in the `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just dump image data into HTML.

You need to either have the file served and link to it or embed the image encoded in base64.