# How to put png side by side to a HTML table using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib figure that is converted to a png :

[image]

```
figure_new.savefig('figure_new.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0
```

and a styler object`report_new`that is rendered as a html table :[image]

```
report_html=fo.write(plunge_results[_j].report_new.render())
```

i use following code to put styler as a HTML table and png image in a HTML file:

```
data_uri = base64.b64encode(open('figure_new.png', 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')

img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(data_uri)

with open('report_new.html','w') as fo :
    report_html=fo.write(plunge_results[_j].report_new.render())
    report_html=fo.write(img_tag)
```

result contains a html table and one image below it , what i need is :

put png image side by side of the html table in the same length or inserting image as a column of the HTML table something like this :

[image]

Comment: I think it's going to be easier to insert the img into the td cells...

Comment: @Andy Hayden this is a AB test  report that produce more than 100 html report and  tables and images are different in each report (structure of table is the same) so i can not edit each HTML one by one i am looking for a way to automatically do that in python

Comment: @sanaz I'm suggesting doing the insert with python rather than manually...

Comment: that is what i do not know how to do

Comment: ok, that wasn't clear, your question only states "side by side".

Comment: @sanaz did you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389567/output-images-to-html-using-python it might help ( it's not exactly the same but it still might help)