# How to load an image file from my local hard drive to html page using python?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Hello I am new to python and I wanted to know how I can load an image from a directory on the computer in a html page using python?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more details to your question, please? It is unclear what is the aim here.

Comment: I have a .png file in my D:\ drive. I want to load the image in a html page using python.

Comment: For clarity, are you running a Python socket-based server to serve HTML files? Or will the code generate an HTML file provided an image file path? The approach will be different for each case. If the code is generating an HTML file, you will need to embed the image inside HTML.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389567/output-images-to-html-using-python, related to your question.